# Cannot run java in my git-annex'ed project

Tags: java, git-annex

I have code of a research project managed by [datalad](https://datalad.org) (which is a frontend for git and git-annex). It contains my code together with a Singularity container for reproducibility.

I installed java manually into this directory. I could run `java -version` initially but once I have committed my changes using `git annex add <java_dir>`, `git add .` and `git commit`, I cannot start java anymore. I get the following error message:

```
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

How can I avoid this incompatibility between java and git-annex?

### (Annex: how I installed java)

```
mkdir lib
cd lib
wget https://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=246799_424b9da4b48848379167015dcc250d8d -O jre_8_341.tgz
tar -xf ./jre_8_341.tgz # creates jre1.8.0_341/
rm jre_8_341.tgz
cd jre1.8.0_341/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the java binary tries to find its own path, as can be seen by calling `strace java -version`:

```
< ... lots of strace output... >
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/proj/.git/annex/objects/X5/f3/M"..., 4096) = 120
< ... more strace output ...>
```

The `readlink` syscall leads into the `.git/annex/objects` directory where git-annex saves big files. Thus, `java` gets the wrong answer what is its installation directory and thus fails.

The solution is to `git annex unlock $JAVA_HOME/bin/java` (where `$JAVA_HOME` is the folder you extracted java to). The same must be done with `$JAVA_HOME/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so` which tries the same manoever.

Finally, the files must be committed in unlocked state. In effect, the files
must not be symlinks into the git-annex object storage but regular files.